# SQL Server 2014 error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql-server

Can you explain this error in SQL Server 2014 Express?

```
SELECT FLOOR(21474837 * 100)    -- doesn't work
SELECT FLOOR(214748370 * 10)    -- doesn't work
SELECT FLOOR(2147483700)        -- works
SELECT FLOOR(21474837 / 0.01)   -- works
```

The number `21474837` is chosen because inferior numbers have no problem neither

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because FLOOR returns same datatype as the input, which is INT in your case. Add some decimals and it will fix it.

```
SELECT FLOOR(21474837.00 * 100)
```

The largest INT number is 2147483647 and 21474837 * 100 = 2147483700, which is 53 too many

Comment: Isn't the root problem how it is handling multiplication and type inference?
  Won't it have the same error even if you don't call `Floor`?

Comment: Yes, it would happen if you didn't call floor and didn't invoke an implicit conversion using a decimal on either multiple or the numerator / denominator. But the question was about floor, so floor I specified my answer towards it. I added a nugget regarding this at the bottom

Comment: I guess my point is, the explanation for why there is an error is not described explicitly by this answer.  The cause of the error relates to type inference and multiplication behaviors.  Multiplying int by int causes the server to assume an int result.  A constant value that is too big for an int will cause the server to use a different data type for the representation.  Dividing by a decimal will result in a decimal result.  The behavior of `FLOOR` is irrelevant more or less.  The solution is correct, but not the explanation.

Comment: Hence *The largest INT number is 2147483647 and 21474837 * 100 = 2147483700, which is 53 too many*

Comment: `21474837 / 0.01` is also 53 too many for an int.  [Better explanation here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151691/arithmetic-overflow-error)

Comment: the solution, I had it, but the reason was strange for me, thanks @scsimon

Comment: @stephen.vakil you are always welcome to add an answer, but 21474837 / 0.01 implicitly converts it to a decimal, hence why `select 
 floor(21474837 / 0.01), 
 SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(floor(21474837 / 0.01),'BaseType')` doesn't error out...